Azure OpenAI assistant model name
I'm trying to make an OpenAI assistant using the Azure OpenAI service, following directions from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/assistant. I've created an Azure resource and deployment ("analytics-chat"), and the endpoint and API from the Azure studio.
My code looks like:
client = AzureOpenAI(
  azure_endpoint=os.getenv("azure_endpoint"),
  api_key=os.getenv("azure_openai_key"),
  api_version="2024-02-15-preview"
)

assistant = client.beta.assistants.create(
    name="MyChatbot",
    instructions="You are a helpful assistant",
    model="analytics-chat" #You must replace this value with the deployment name for your model. <- from the MS Azure docs
)

This code always fails with the message:
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': 'model', 'code': 'model_not_found'}}

I've tried every combination of deployment name, model name ("analytics-chat", "gpt-4", "gpt-4-0125", "gpt-4-1025-preview", etc etc.), but I always get that same error. As mentioned above the deployment name is "analytics-chat".
Online examples always seem to include the model name (like 'gpt-4') for the model argument, but the documentation makes it clear that the model argument should be actually the deployment name. In any case, nothing works here. Any ideas what a valid model name looks like here? TIA

According to this MS-Document,
The Assistants API, SDK, Azure AI Studio, and Azure OpenAI Studio are available only in selected regions.
In my environment, I created an OpenAI resource in the australiaeast location, and I created a model with the name analyticschat (gpt-4 1106-Preview).

Now, I passed the credentials and ran the same code you shared. It executed successfully.
Code:
import os
import json
from openai import AzureOpenAI
    
client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_key=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"),  
    api_version="2024-02-15-preview",
    azure_endpoint =os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT")"
    )

# Create an assistant
assistant = client.beta.assistants.create(
    name="MyChatbot",
    instructions="You are a helpful assistant",
    model="analyticschat" #You must replace this value with the deployment name for your model. <- from the MS Azure docs
)

print(assistant.model_dump_json(indent=2))

Output:
{
  "id": "asst_DiNfdwxxxxgbF4B",
  "created_at": 17xxxx22,
  "description": null,
  "file_ids": [],
  "instructions": "You are a helpful assistant",
  "metadata": {},
  "model": "analyticschat",
  "name": "MyChatbot",
  "object": "assistant",
  "tools": []
}


